# MVC Ajax partial view not updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I cannot get the partial view to update. If I refresh the page manually, I do see the incremented count. I tried similar approach without partial view inside the countDiv with action returning a random integer and the countDiv was getting updated just fine, so its something about the partial view:

Main view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddPositive", new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", Model.Id } }, 
new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "countDiv"}))
{
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="For" />
    </div>
}

<div id="countDiv">
    @Html.Partial("PollCounts")       
</div>
```

PollsCounts partial view:

```
@model MyProj.Models.Poll
<div>Positive: @Model.PositiveCount</div>
<div>Negative: @Model.NegativeCount</div>
```

Action:

```
public PartialViewResult AddPositive(int id)
{
    Poll poll = db.Polls.Find(id);
    db.Entry(poll).State = EntityState.Modified;
    poll.PositiveCount++;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return PartialView("CountsPartial", poll);

}
```

Comment: Not sure why the colours are messed up. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look in your action, you're returning the countsPartial instead of the pollsCount partial view

Comment: Argghhh, sorry to waste your time. I changed the name of partial view due to same problem, fixed the error and forgot to change the name. Thanks again.